# Java AWT Menu and TextArea not showing

Tags: java, java-8, awt, textarea, frame

I can't manage to display menu and textarea with awt (see the code below). What could be the problem? I think I'm doing everything correctly, but could it be caused by the fact, that Frame object isn't instantiated while I'm trying to add TextArea and Menu to it?

BTW. I know AWT is obsolete, but I want to gain some knowledge of it before moving onto Swing or JavaFX. Also point me to any mistakes I've made while creating this post (as it's the first of mine).

```
class Notepad extends Frame{
  Notepad(String name){
    super(name);
    TextArea text = new TextArea(" ", 10, 30, SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    add(text);

    MenuBar mbar = new MenuBar();
    setMenuBar(mbar);

    Menu file = new Menu("File");
    MenuItem New, Open, Save, Close;
    file.add(New = new MenuItem("New"));
    file.add(Open = new MenuItem("Open"));
    file.add(Save = new MenuItem("Save"));
    file.add(Close = new MenuItem("Close"));
    mbar.add(file);

    Menu edit = new Menu("Edit");
    MenuItem Find, Replace, ReplaceAll;
    edit.add(Find = new MenuItem("Find"));
    edit.add(Replace = new MenuItem("Replace"));
    edit.add(ReplaceAll = new MenuItem("ReplaceAll"));
    mbar.add(edit);

    MenuHandler menuHandler = new MenuHandler(this);
    New.addActionListener(menuHandler);
    Open.addActionListener(menuHandler);
    Save.addActionListener(menuHandler);
    Close.addActionListener(menuHandler);

    Find.addActionListener(menuHandler);
    Replace.addActionListener(menuHandler);
    ReplaceAll.addActionListener(menuHandler);

    MyWindowAdapter w_listener = new MyWindowAdapter(this);
    addWindowListener(w_listener);

    //this.setVisible(true);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
  }
  public static void main(String[] foo){
    Notepad notepad = new Notepad("Notepad");
    notepad.setSize(500, 500);
    notepad.setVisible(true);
  }

}
class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter{
  Notepad notepad;
  MyWindowAdapter(Notepad notepadframe){
    this.notepad = notepad;
  }

  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
    notepad.setVisible(false);
    System.exit(0);
  }
}

class MenuHandler implements ActionListener{
  Notepad notepad;

  public MenuHandler(Notepad notepad){
    this.notepad = notepad;
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    String arg = ae.getActionCommand();
    if(arg.equals("New")){

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your constructor for your `MyWindowAdapter` class is not doing anything. You need to change it to `this.notepad = notepadframe;` or rename the parameter to `notepad`. Just an observation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was renaming NotepadFrame to Notepad and that had to be the mistake. Greatly appreciated

Comment: Even with that error, I was still getting the menu's and textarea to show up. Can you see them now?

Comment: Yes, continuing my work. I agree, it's really strange, but everything's fine now.